# Is garbage collection used in production quality Cocoa apps?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, garbage-collection

I'm mainly wondering about the affect that garbage collection would have on performance. Is the use of garbage collection frowned upon for release apps?

Another concern that I can think of is that using garbage collection could lead to sloppier programming.

Do you use garbage collection in your apps?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Garbage Collection is used in many production quality applications.  Xcode, Automator, System Preferences and several other system applications are GC'd, and you can expect that trend to continue over time.

As well, many developers have embraced GC and are using it exclusively in their applications.   Intuit's new versions of Quicken and QuickBooks for the Mac are garbage collected, for example.

There are a number of advantages of GC, too.  Off the top of my head and from personal experience:

- it makes multithreading easier;  a simple assign is an atomic declaration of ownership
- it offloads a bunch of memory management to other cores; it is naturally concurrent and offloads a bunch computation from the main thread (or computation threads)
- in many cases, allocation and deallocation can happen entirely within the context of a thread, thus eliminating any need for global synchronization or locking
- the collector has gotten faster with each release of Mac OS X and that trend will continue (just as it has with the rest of the system).  By offloading more of your app's computational load to the system provided frameworks, your app will gain more and more from optimizations to the underlying system.
- because the collector has intimate knowledge of the object graph -- of the pointers between objects -- in memory, it makes analysis and debugging significantly easier.   Instead of "where did this dangling pointer come from?", the question is now "Give me a list of reasons why this object is sticking around longer than I think it should?".

This isn't to say that there isn't work to do to make your application work optimally under GC.  There certainly are such tasks!

Comment: Worth noting that garbage collection has been deprecated in 10.8.

Comment: It's now worth noting that 10.11 will be the last version of OS X to include the garbage collection runtime. Apps that use garbage collection may not run properly or at all on 10.12.

Answer (score 5):

Garbage collection has been around since the 1960s and is used in many released applications. All .NET apps use garbage collection. Apple uses libauto in Xcode.

Garbage collection generally leads to better quality apps in Cocoa since the developer is freed from the memory management burden. There are tons of Cocoa apps that leak! (though it may not a significant  amount of memory)

I tend to use gc since since I can turn around my apps faster and don't have to worry about messaging zombie objects!

Comment: There are also tons of garbage collected apps that leak. It is just very likely that they leak less.

Answer (score 3):

I use GC whenever I can, because the best code of all is the code you don't have to write in the first place.  Also, as Bbum pointed out above, running under GC means that you have far more information available for performance analysis, should you need to debug any bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is recommended for any new Cocoa applications, and Apple eats its own dog food by using it in Xcode.  Performance is an interesting situation, because while you're most likely going to be consuming more CPU cycles overall, the application may actually end up faster in some areas due to multithreading of the collector and the simplification of accessor methods.

Computers are made to do work for us.  Cocoa's reference counting is usually easy to manage, but garbage collection is one more thing it can do now--let the machine do the work so you can focus on things that matter!

Answer (score 1):

Like the others, I would strongly recommend using GC.  The performance overhead usually is negligible!  I don't need to repeat the benefits as stated by other users.

However, I would strongly encourage writing libraries, as opposed to applications, to run in a non-GC mode as well.  Some environments cannot run GC code, the iPhone being the notable one; so if you created an internal library for yourself, that you envision reusing it later for an iPhone app, then I would recommend designing it so it would work in a non-GC environment as well.

Converting a GC code to non-GC code is much more difficult than the other way around!

Comment: Despite the fact that some environments (such as iPhone and pre-Leopard) don't support GC, you can compile libraries in dual mode. It takes a little extra work, but it's certainly possible. I've done it for the open-source CHDataStructures framework myself.

Comment: @Quinn, Cannot agree more.  However, I clarified my post to indicate that i meant that libraries should be written to be useable in non-GC environments.