# Avoid memory trashing

Tags: cocoa, macos, garbage-collection

I'm working on a Mac application that uses garbage collection. The application crashes for a few users and the crash logs indicate that it has something to do with memory corruption or memory trashing.

I post the important bit of the crash log below.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc[81831]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   libSystem.B.dylib                  0x00007fffffe00847 __memcpy + 167
1   libauto.dylib                      0x00007fff82718170 auto_zone_write_barrier_memmove + 96
2   libauto.dylib                      0x00007fff8271916e auto_realloc(_malloc_zone_t*, void*, unsigned long) + 878
3   libSystem.B.dylib                  0x00007fff8346e0db malloc_zone_realloc + 92
4   com.apple.Foundation               0x00007fff83169836 _NSMutableDataGrowBytes + 652
5   com.apple.Foundation               0x00007fff83169513 -[NSConcreteMutableData appendBytes:length:] + 101
6   MY.Application                     0x000000010000b9cd -[Connection stream:handleEvent:] + 376
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation           0x00007fff85742373 _signalEventSync + 115
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation           0x00007fff857422e4 _cfstream_solo_signalEventSync + 116
```

What happens is, my application receives data from the network and writes that data to an NSMutableData object. I have talked about this with some other developers and our best guess is that memory is being trashed, which causes the crash.

The question is how do you prevent memory trashing and how do you debug bugs like this in Xcode?

For completeness, I also post the code of the method that leads up to the crash.

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    switch(eventCode) {
          case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
               if (stream == outputStream) {
                    [self writeBufferToStream];
               }
               break;
          }

          case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            if (stream == inputStream) {
               readReady = YES;
            } else {
               writeReady = YES;
            }

            if ([self isReadyForUse] && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connectionReadyForUse:)])
               [delegate connectionReadyForUse:self];
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
               if (stream == inputStream) {
                    int bytesRead = 0;

                    static uint8_t buffer[kBufferSize];
                    bytesRead = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    [inBuffer appendBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];

                    //** Process buffer contents **//

                    BOOL safe = YES;

                    while (safe) {
                         if (inSize <= 0) {
                              if ([inBuffer length] >= sizeof(uint64_t)) {
                                   memcpy(&inSize, [inBuffer bytes], sizeof(uint64_t));
                                   NSRange rangeToDelete = {0, sizeof(uint64_t)};
                                   [inBuffer replaceBytesInRange:rangeToDelete withBytes:NULL length:0];

                              } else {
                                   break;
                              }
                         }

                         if (inSize > 0) {
                              if ([inBuffer length] >= inSize) {
                                   NSMutableData *packetData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[inBuffer bytes] length:inSize];                                        
                                   [delegate connection:self receivedData:packetData];

                                   safe = NO;

                                   NSRange rangeToDelete = {0, inSize};
                                   [inBuffer replaceBytesInRange:rangeToDelete withBytes:NULL length:0];
                                   inSize = 0;
                              } else {
                                   break;
                              }
                         } else {
                              break;
                         }
                    }
               }
            break;
               }

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {

            NSError *theError = [stream streamError];
            if (stream == inputStream)
                if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connection:encounteredReadError:)])
                    [delegate connection:self encounteredReadError:theError];
                else{
                    if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connection:encounteredWriteError:)])
                        [delegate connection:self encounteredWriteError:theError];   
                }
            break;
        }

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
            if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connectionDisconnected:)])
                [delegate connectionDisconnected:self];

            readReady = NO;
            writeReady = NO;
            break;
          }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you know you get about 90x the performance without GC? Adding a line that says release shouldn't be too hard

Comment: @Antwan van Houdt: You might want to take a look at a few advantages of garbage collection (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992755/is-garbage-collection-used-in-production-quality-cocoa-apps. Garbage collection is not a matter of being lazy, but one way (not the holy grail) to optimize and simplify memory management.

Comment: @Antwan, you know you get about 900x the performance without using compiled language? Using the assembly language that uses CPU instructions directly shouldn't be too hard

Comment: @Yuji nice comparison, however adding 1 line instead of writing 90x more is a big difference. You mad? Cos GC is lazy? Lets make our app as bloated as we possibly can because we are too lazy to do primary school level counting :D 1 + 1 = 2 oh wait its 4 no? so difficult :/

Comment: @Bart: sorry for doing unrelated discussion here, and sorry for not being able to help you. The only possible place in a GC app where it can lead to memory corruption is where you directly deal with C arrays and non-object pointers. So check all those places. Another thing is that you shouldn't use `NSMutableData` from more than one thread; that can cause a strange crash like this.

Comment: Thanks, Yuji. I don't entirely understand your last sentence. Why shouldn't one use NSMutableData from more than one thread (and where do I do that)? What's the alternative.

Answer (score -1):

keep your data reading and writing in same thread. If you must do it in multi thread, you can choose lock or barrier to make that thread safe